# Prove that under ZF, $\forall x (\bigcap \{z:z\notin x\} = \emptyset)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I am taking a view on the chapter on set theory in Hinman and discovered this statement as Exercise 6.1.27.

May I please ask for a proof of it? The claim is a bit interesting, it says ``for every set $x$, the intersection of the collection of sets that is not in it is empty''. What does it reveal? Is there any interesting application of this result?

Comment: Did you try to guess interpretation of this fact?

Comment: @user14111 Sorry, I mean the intersection of such a collection. I have edited it to correct.

Comment: @AdamWrzesiński I suppose you have a hint. May I please ask what would it be?

Comment: I understand the downvotes because I did not write any attempt. But honestly, I do not see any approach to the problem. I beg for a hint.

Comment: If the axiom of regularity (foundation) is available, then two elements of $\{z:x\notin x\}$ are $x$ and $\{x\}$, and $x\cap\{x\}=\varnothing$. If that axiom is not available, then it's somewhat more complicated.

Comment: I don’t get it. $\{z:z \notin x \}$ is not a set.

Comment: @user14111 Thank you very much! I see, my stupid. Hinman's formulation of ZF does include AF. But do you think this is true if AF is not available?

Comment: @Porky $\{z:z\notin x\}$ is not a set, it is a class. The intersection of a nonempty class exists and is a set.

Comment: Yes, I think it's true if AF is not available. That might be worth another question.

Comment: @user14111 Here is the link for the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866211/does-bigcap-zz-notin-x-emptyset-hold-for-every-set-x-in-zf-af Thank you for any further explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no classes in ZF, but you can still write expressions with classes that represent abbreviations.

So $y \in \cap \{z:z \notin x\}$ means $\forall r (r \in \{z:z \notin x\} \rightarrow y \in r)$ or equivalently $\forall r (r \notin x \rightarrow  y \in r )$.

So if we can find a set not in $x$ that doesnt contain $y$ we have shown  $\forall r (r \notin x \rightarrow  y \in r )$ is false and so $y\in \cap \{z:z \notin x\}$ is false and so $\cap \{z:z \notin x\}=\phi$.

But we know $x$ does not contain every singleton set (an easy proof). So, there is a singleton set, say $\{ t\}$ which is not in $x$. But then $x \cup \{\{t\}\}$ does not contain every singleton set. So there are at least two singleton sets not in $x$. And $y$ is not in both of these. Hence $\forall r (r \notin x \rightarrow  y \in r )$ is false and so $\cap \{z:z \notin x\}=\phi$. As this holds for arbitrary $x$, $\forall x(\cap \{z:z \notin x\}=\phi)$

Answer (score 1):

According to the axiom of Foundation, we have: $(x \in \{z:z \notin x\})$ and $(\{x\} \in \{z:z \notin x\})$
from this we can infer $(\bigcap\{z\mid z\notin x\}\subseteq x\cap\{x\}=\varnothing)
$.