# Does $(\bigcap \{z:z\notin x\} = \emptyset)$ hold for every set $x$ in ZF$-$AF?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I asked about this and the answer is true if we assume AF. As a more interesting question, does it still hold without AF? According to the suggestion in the comment, I should post it as another question.

Original question: [Prove that under ZF, $\forall x (\bigcap \{z:z\notin x\} = \emptyset)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866146/prove-that-under-zf-forall-x-bigcap-zz-notin-x-emptyset?noredirect=1#comment10374685_4866146)

Comment: I believe it's independent of ZF - AF whether V is a set. If it is then this is false, and there's trivially models where it's true, so I presume this is independent of ZF - AF.

Comment: $V$ contains all ordinals, so it's not a set even in ZF-AF.

Comment: Taking from the answer in the linked question, the idea of using $a\ne b$ such that $\{a\},\{b\}\notin x$ works with union+comprehension+pairing.

Comment: Maybe a more interesting question, what if we let x be a Proper Class- does this still hold? Hint: Does it work if x is V? If not, are there any other Proper Classes it wouldnt hold fot?

Comment: Also, in response to above: V is a Proper Class with just Comprehension + Probably Extentionality  as you can get a contradiction showcasing that the Russell Class is a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivially, since $\{\{a\}\mid a=a\}$ is a proper class, pick $a\neq b$ such that $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are both not in $x$. Then $\bigcap\{y\mid y\notin x\}\subseteq\{a\}\cap\{b\}=\varnothing$.

The choice of $a$ and $b$ can be made "more canonical" either by constructing these directly from $x$ as some subsets whose singletons are not in $x$, or, perhaps more simply, the least two ordinals that can be chosen to work for $x$, as the class of ordinals is a proper class.

Comment: It is smart to use ordinals! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Given a set $x$, let $z=\{y\in x\cup(\bigcup x):y\notin y\}$. Then $z\notin z$ and $z\notin x\cup(\bigcup x)$, so we have $z,\{z\}\notin x$ and $z\cap\{z\}=\varnothing$.

Alternatively, filling in the details from Asaf Karagila's answer, let $a=\{z\in\bigcup x:z\notin z\}$ and $b=\{z\in\{a\}\cup(\bigcup x\}):z\notin z\}$; then $\{a\},\{b\}\notin x$ and $\{a\}\cap\{b\}=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

$\bigcap\{z:z\notin x\} = \varnothing$ is equivalent to
$$\forall y,\quad\exists z\notin x,\quad y\notin z.$$
For each $y$, the class $\{z:y\notin z\}$ is proper hence cannot be contained in the set $x$.